# Change order or tabs on product details page on Magento 1.9

Tags: attributes, magento-1.9, tabs, product-view

How do you change the order of the tabs on the product details page.

I created a new tab called 'Programs' by adding the below to my local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.programs" as="programs" template="catalog/product/view/programs.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Programs</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

I aslo created a catalog/product/view/programs.phtml template in my theme.

In addition I created another tab called ingredients

Now I have 3 tabs on my product details page i.e. Description, Reviews, Programs & Ingredients.

How can I change the order to Programs Description Ingredients and Reviews?

Also, how can I link my the templates I created for these new tabs to a product attribute?

Comment: you may use following third party script to re order tabs on product page....https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fme-home-tabs.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the before or after tag in your block. Here is an [official](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/controlling-block-order) guide to achieve that.

Example:

```
 <block type="cms/block" before="some-other-block" name="left.permanent.callout">
```

Comment: Cool. Remember to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Do you know how I can link my the templates I created for these new tabs to a product attribute?

Comment: Make another question for that please.

Answer (score 0):

I have also similar requirement, I have `Specifications and Description tabs` and I have to swap their positions on the product details page. 
Therefore in the `catalog.xml`, I have changed the below code

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Specifications</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
                </block>
```

to

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Specifications</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" after="product.attributes" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
                </block>
```

Basically, I have added the after attribute in the block tag.